# Postgres query find UNique Latest entry

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a Postgres Table named ip_storage_table and it is storing three values ip_address , virtual_id and a time_stamp

The actual relation between this is initially all I/Ps are having a virtual_id associated with it for eg:

```
192.168.1.1 has 1000 at 2015-07-20 15:00:00
192.168.1.2 has 2000 at 2015-07-20 15:00:00
192.168.1.3 has 3000 at 2015-07-20 15:00:00
```

This table contains the virtual_id of each I/P address at a particular time stamp so it can have more entries like

```
192.168.1.1 has 3000 at 2015-07-20 16:00:00
192.168.1.2 has 1000 at 2015-07-20 16:00:00
192.168.1.3 has 2000 at 2015-07-20 16:00:00
192.168.1.2 has 4000 at 2015-07-20 17:00:00
192.168.1.1 has 2000 at 2015-07-20 18:00:00
```

I want to run a query such that:

1. The virtual_id comes only once in the output
2. The i/p associated with the virtual_id should come with it
3. and the virtual_id should be latest i.e. in above example 2000 will be with 192.168.1.1 and at 18:00:00 timestamp and all its previous values wont be displayed
4. If two virtual id's have the same i/p , only the latest one appears in the output

I could have uploaded an image of the database, but I am using Linux and unable to find image editing tools, if you can't get a view of database with above description let me know, I will try again

Comment: "*I could have uploaded an image of the database*" - please don't post "images" for sample data. Post formatted SQL statements, or create a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: The fastest query depends on data distribution, indexes and your version of Postgres. Do you want the latest `virtual_id` per `ip_address ` like the first half of the question suggests, or the latest `ip_address` per  `virtual_id` like your second half of the question suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (virtual_id) t.*
from mytable t
order by virtual_id, time_stamp desc;
```

This will return each `virtual_id` with its more recent row.

Comment: Executing: "SELECT DISTINCT ON (virtual_id) mytable.* FROM TABLE mytable ORDER BY virtual_id, time_stamp desc;"
Result: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TABLE" at character 54

I am getting an error with this query

Comment: @matta118 . . . "table" is intended to be your table name.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try:-

```
SELECT i/p, MIN(virtual_id), MAX(timestamp)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY i/p;
```

Hope this helps.

See the fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d7905/5

Comment: sorry it is producing duplicate results

Comment: According to fiddle whoch row should not come??